# Preserving html format in creating tasks from email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a little script that converts an email into a Task in my outlook.

My main frustration is that it won't preserve the html format, and deals with embedded images as attachments. I was wondering if anyone could help. I know it is possible as I've copied the body of an email directly across to the body of a task manually and it is preserved fine.

```
Sub ConvertSelectedMailtoTask()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    Set objApp = Application

    If TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow) = "Explorer" Then
        For Each objMail In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            If Left(objMail.Subject, 3) = "RE:" Or Left(objMail.Subject, 3) = "FW:" Then
                subj = Right(objMail.Subject, Len(objMail.Subject) - 4)
            Else
                subj = objMail.Subject
            End If
            With objTask
                .Subject = subj
                .Importance = objMail.Importance
                .StartDate = objMail.ReceivedTime
                .Body = objMail.Body
                .DueDate = Date + 3
                If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    CopyAttachments objMail, objTask
                End If
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderTime = Date + 2.5
                .Sensitivity = olPrivate
                .Save
            End With
        Next
    ElseIf TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
        Set objMail = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

        If Left(objMail.Subject, 3) = "RE:" Or Left(objMail.Subject, 3) = "FW:" Then
                subj = Right(objMail.Subject, Len(objMail.Subject) - 4)
            Else
                subj = objMail.Subject
            End If
            With objTask
                .Subject = subj
                .Importance = objMail.Importance
                .StartDate = objMail.ReceivedTime
                .Body = objMail.Body
                .DueDate = Date + 3
                If objMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    CopyAttachments objMail, objTask
                End If
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderTime = Date + 2.5
                .Sensitivity = olPrivate
                .Save
            End With
    End If
    Set objTask = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

And here is the script for the attachments

```
Sub CopyAttachments(objSourceItem, objTargetItem)
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
   strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
   For Each objAtt In objSourceItem.Attachments
      strFile = strPath & objAtt.FileName
      objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
      objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , , objAtt.DisplayName
      fso.DeleteFile strFile
   Next

   Set fldTemp = Nothing
   Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Update:**

I found a bit of code that uses a word document to preserve the formatting:

```
Sub CopyFullBody(sourceItem As Object, targetItem As Object)
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    Dim objDoc2 As Word.Document
    Dim objSel2 As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    ' get a Word.Selection from the source item
    Set objDoc = sourceItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
    If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
        objSel.WholeStory
        objSel.Copy
        Set objDoc2 = targetItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
        If Not objDoc2 Is Nothing Then
            Set objSel2 = objDoc2.Windows(1).Selection
            objSel2.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not get Word.Document for " & _
                   targetItem.Subject
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not get Word.Document for " & _
               sourceItem.Subject
    End If
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objDoc2 = Nothing
    Set objSel2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

This doesn't seem like it would be the only solution hence updating my own post instead of answering my question as this seems a bit long winded (using another application just to give me formatting, when I can copy and paste text manually just fine all in Outlook). If anyone has any other thoughts on this/defining attachment types please carry on answering!

Answer (score 0):

in the line

```
.Body = objMail.Body
```

you only ask fot the non-formatted Body. Try instead:

```
.Body = objMail.htmlBody
```

and something completely different: I just put reminders onto the emails themselves, so I have no need to create extra Tasks at all...

Comment: Thanks but tried both of these. Second one I just get the body full of HTML code. I was putting reminders on my emails automatically, but for whatever it wasn't creating reminders that were being synced with the server (Used to at my old job)

Comment: if you would also be happy with reminders on your emails, i would check why they aren't synced tot the Server. Are reminders set manually synced - if yes, your code might not change all reminder-fields necessary. Let me know, then I adopt the answer.

Comment: It's a 13k people company with outdated sharepoint and server (2007) packages. I won't be able to get anything changed at the server hence looking for a workaround. I did have it set up to automatically flag all email with a due date for the end of the week, but it wasn't triggering reminders to sync with my iPhone calendars (which is why I'm looking for a work around) Could you detail how you set yours up just in case I am missing something? Thanks a lot

Comment: as far as I know Iphones to not copy the reminders in emails, that's not your Servers but Apple's fault (they even don't have privacy-Settings in the calendar, that is really bad!!!) They only Show that an email has been flagged, but nothing more - by the way Android is no better there! After some time I learned to be quite happy with that, because the email-reminders only come on the PC, and "real" reminders from Tasks and calendar on the mobile. So in the ned you will have to copy your mails into Tasks, as planned... As Dimitri Points you to redemption, you have a challenge I can't help...

Comment: Strangely as said above it used to work at my old company just fine, on an older server. Maybe they've lost a bit of functionality somewhere along the line. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Outlook tasks, appointments and tasks work with RTF, not HTML. hence `TaskItem`, `ContactItem` and `AppointmentItem` objects only expose the `RtfBody` property, but not `HTMLBody` (like `MailItem` does).

You will need to either convert HTML to RTF (you can try the Word Object Model for that) or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author): unlike Outlook Object Model, it exposes the [RDOTaskItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAppointmenItem.htm).`HTMLBody` property and dynamically converts HTML to the native (for tasks) RTF when that property is set.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the `RTFBody` property can not be set, but that setting `Body` to an RTF byte array works as expected.